# Interfacing android usb port with sl4a python

Tags: android, python, usb, pyserial, sl4a

i am trying to interface an external hardware with my android device by using python through sl4a,
can you guys tell me how i can read and write data from and to usb port?

i have tried pyserial module,
but what i found is, it needs a usb to rs232 converter and usb host drivers and pl2303 drivers in kernel...i am a bit confused,
i am using htc one v android 4.0.3,
titanium kiss kernel(very close to stock kernel)

can anyone push me in right direction.

Tell me if pyserial will work for me or it need anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pyserial is not working due to [missing drivers in the Android kernel](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/issues/192).

However [sl4a has builtin USB Host Serial support with good compatibility](https://github.com/kuri65536/sl4a/blob/master/USBHostSerialFacade.md) ([example code here](https://github.com/kuri65536/sl4a/blob/master/android/USBHostSerialFacade/samplescripts/testusbserial.py)).